# Error: Unable to find an element with the role "alert" (react-testing-library example)

Tags: react-testing-library

I'm using the stock codesandbox example from `react-testing-library` and I've added two files, `Login.jsx` and `__tests__/Login.js` . These files are copied directly from the `react-testing-library` examples on the main readme.md.

However, when the test suites run, I get an error:

**Error: Unable to find an element with the role "alert**

When I debug this, the html output does not appear to have any role attributes in any of the divs.  What am I doing wrong?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-examples-dh1e7

Comment: The code makes sense to me. Does it work locally?

Comment: it does not.  I get the same error locally.  Not quite why as this is the stock example from the main documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late. But anyway.

Your components does not set `success` field it relies later on:

```
{state.success ? (
  <div role="alert">Congrats! You're signed in!</div>
) : null}
```

Probably it should be `state.resolved`